# How do I convert double or float or negative number to binary without using Integer.toBinaryString in java?

Tags: java, floating-point, binary, negative-number

I've found this method and it works amazing with positive numbers of byte/short/int/long types, but doesn't work correctly if I type float/double or negative number. The reason why I need to do it without using `Integer.toBinaryString()` is that I've got this task at school and our teacher said that we cant use it.

```java
private static String toBinary(long d) {
    String s = "";
    while (d > 0) {
        s = ((d % 2) == 0 ? "0" : "1") + s;
        d = d / 2;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I didnt understand, to what result and where i should add minus..? Ive tried this with math.abs also, didnt work too. Like, if i type -128000, it should convert to 11111111 11111110 00001100 00000000, according to Integer.toBinaryString but instead, this program converts it like a positive number and i get 11111010000000000

Comment: If the number to be converted is negative, what should the result look like?  Do you want to print with a `-` sign, or do you want the result to be in twos-complement form?

Comment: I want it to be the same as the Integer.toBinaryString result

Comment: two's-complement, then. Are you allowed to use bitwise operators? Are you allowed to use bitwise methods?

Comment: Idk what it is, so I guess i can

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html  
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

Comment: for two's complement (I somehow missed that in the question) also consider the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) to `toBinaryString()`: "*Returns a string representation of the integer argument as an unsigned integer in base 2.
The unsigned integer value is the argument plus 2³² if the argument is negative; otherwise it is equal to the argument. This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra leading 0s.*"

Comment: so adding 2³² and then converting it with the given code will not work?

Comment: But i still didnt understand what to do with the float numbers. I didnt find anything useful at the oracle docs

Comment: Java offers no direct means of manipulating bits for floating point types. However, it does offer a means of copying the bits in a way that allows manipulation of the copy. First, see [Java Primitives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) . Note that `float` and `double` use 32 bit and 64 bit versions respectively of [IEEE 745](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard. [This image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#/media/File:Float_example.svg) is helpful.

Comment: Then, check the [Float API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) and the [Double API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) for methods that have **bit** as part of the name.

Comment: Is this a pure mathematical question? I.e. _How do I compute the value of a real number in base 2?_ Or is this a question to find out the binary representation of an IEEE754 floating point number? Or is this a question to find the binary representation of a IEEE754 floating point number, stored in your PC (little vs big endian).

Comment: Is this statement _((d % 2) == 0 ? "0" : "1")_ not over-redundant? `d%2` actually gives those results.

Comment: might be worth looking at hex formatting (i.e. `%a`) of floating point numbers provided via `java.util.Formatter`.  i.e. `0.1` is formatted as `0x1.999999999999ap-4`.  this is a direct translation of how the IEEE754 represents numbers rather than the decimal expansion that is commonly used

Comment: @kvantour this is a pure mathematical question, i believe. I just need to get the float number in base 2 and print in into the console

Comment: Java offers bit manipulation operators and methods for integer types, but not for floating  point types. However, [Float API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) and [Double API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) have `floatToIntBits` and `doubleToLongBits` (with or without `Raw`) that copy the bits to an `int` or `long`, which can be bitwise manipulated. They also have `toHexString` methods.

Comment: @Cat : the teacher only said u can't use `Integer.toBinaryString()` - they never said you aren't allowed to semi-cheat by first calling a system function to convert the input to base16 hex or base8 octal , then essentially do a 1-to-1 mapping back to binary string

Comment: @Cat : ps : `floats/doubles` is really just a mantissa of bits paired with sign and binary exponent - the quick and dirty way is to rescale the exponent till it's in the same zone as unsigned int of that mantissa - then make those bits, and linearly adjust the decimal point accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** the code below is written in pseudo language

Assume we are interested in the binary representation of *f*, then there a couple of steps to be done. Let's assume that `s` contains the binary string and is initialized to "0."

1. determine the sign

   ```
   s=" 0."; 
   if (f < 0) { s = "-0."; f = -f  }
   ```
2. determine the exponent: searching for *n*, such that *0.5 ≤ f × 2<sup>n</sup> < 1* :

   ```
   n=0; while ( f < 0.5 || f >= 1) { n += (f > 1 ? 1:-1); f *= (f > 1 ? 0.5 : 2) }
   ```
3. determine the digits

   ```
   f *= 2
   while (f != 0) {
      if (f > 0) {s += "1" : f -= 1 } 
      else { s += "0" }
      f *= 2
   }
   ```

   We assume the stopping condition to be `f != 0` as each IEEE number is numerically a finite number that is a linear combination of powers of two.
4. Print the value

   ```
   print s "E" n
   ```

Here is a quick `awk` line that does the above:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { f = sqrt(42); n = 0
              s=(f<0 ? "-0." : " 0."); f=(f<0 ? -f : f)
              while ( f < 0.5 || f >= 1) { n += (f>1 ? 1 : -1); f*=(f>1?0.5:2) };
              f *= 2
              while ( f != 0 ) { s = s (f > 1); f = (f - (f>=1))*2 }        
              print s "E" n
      }'
 0.110011110110001000111010010100010011000010010011000E3
```

Comment: Thanks, tho ive already found the answer. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

`mawk` has an undocumented backdoor for you to directly extract out the full IEEE 754 hex (not just the `"%A"` format) :

```
mawk 'BEGIN { CONVFMT = "IEEE754-%lX"

     print (  exp(_^_)     "")
     print (atan2(_<_,--_) "") }'
```

> ```
> IEEE754 - 400 5BF0A8B145769   # Euler''s E 2.71828...
> IEEE754 - 400 921FB54442D18   #         PI 3.14159…
> ```

you can also see from this next section how sign bit or the exponent bits flip for `pi/4`, `-pi/4`, and when I rescale it down by another `2 ^ 1015` :

> ```
> IEEE754 - BFE 921FB54442D18     #      negative
> IEEE754 - 3FE 921FB54442D18     # "non-negative"
>
> IEEE754 - 007 921FB54442D18
> ```

and when it goes into denormalized zone, all the hex digits downshift in unison :

```
 print (atan2(_^=_<_,_)*2^-1021 "")
 print (atan2(_^=_<_,_)*2^-1029 "")
```

> ```
> IEEE754 - 001 921FB54442D18
> IEEE754 - 000 01921FB54442D
> ```

Comment: Thanks, tho ive already found the answer. Thanks anyways